# Query for correlated tables

Tags: mysql, database

I am currently trying to run a query that will show all tables that correlate with each other. I did not make the table design. So I am running into some trouble in making: It's not clear how `office_hours` table correlates with `schedule` table? Overall how can I display properly all tables that correlate through a query?

```
SELECT * 
FROM schedule
INNER JOIN semester ON schedule.semester_id = semester.id
INNER JOIN office_hours ON office_hours.id = schedule.???
```

Comment: look at the foreign keys defined (assuming of course the designers thought to include them...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `ID` from table `schedule` is only an `auto_increment` column and the proper way to join `schedule` from `office_hours` is `office_hours.schedule_id = schedule.semester_id`.

```
select      *
from        schedule 
            inner join semester 
                on schedule.semester_id = semester.id
            inner join office_hours
                on office_hours.schedule_id = schedule.semester_id
```

**UPDATE 1**

```
select      *
from        schedule 
            inner join semester 
                on schedule.semester_id = semester.id
            inner join office_hours
                on office_hours.schedule_id = schedule.semester_id
            INNER JOIN faculty
                ON faculty.id = office_hours.faculty_id
            INNER JOIN Section
                ON Section.faculty_ID = faculty.id AND
                    Section.Schedule_ID = Schedule.ID
            INNER JOIN class
                ON Class.ID = Section.Class_ID
            INNER JOIN major_class_br
                ON major_class_br.class_ID = Class.ID
            INNER JOIN  major_minor 
                ON major_class_br.major_minor_id = major_minor.ID
```

it is assumed that all `ID` or *linking columns* exists on each table that is why `INNER JOIN` was used. Otherwise, use `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: I'd guess, `schedule.semester_id` correlates with `semester.id`, doesn't it?

Comment: is there away to include the `faculty`, `class`, `major_minor`, `major_class_br` tables in that query? Sorry i am very new to this

Comment: Thank you, its giving me an error with the `section` table. Error: -unknow column `section.schedule_id`-

Comment: what is the complete error that has been thrown? Weird, `schedule_id` is present on `section` table.

Comment: @JohnWoo My friend will you help me with this. I am trying to create those tables in my own data base. here is the link for the question: [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13262615/construct-query-to-create-tables)

Answer (score 0):

You must use the id, which is in both tables:

```
...
inner join office_hours on office_hours.schedule_id = schedule.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Tryu this:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
SCHEDULE 
INNER JOIN semester 
ON schedule.semester_id = semester.id
INNER JOIN office_hours
ON office_hours.schedule_id = schedule.id
```