# Populating fields in MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, database

I have currently created a total of 12 tables in MySQL database. 11 of those tables share correlated data and are indexing with each other. I am undergoing some difficulties populating the values in each individual field of the tables and making sure they index properly. I was wondering if there is an easier way that I can populate each field in all tables for one record without doing it manually and having to worry for the proper `foreign_key` matches with the other table(indexing). Possibly a query can do the job but I am not sure how I can build such query. Or any other suggestions specifically tying to this example.

Below are links to the desing of tables and a query if you will like to create an exact copy of tables in my database.

[TABLE STRUCTURE/DESIGN](http://webprolearner.ueuo.com/class_des/table_structure.php)

[QUERY FOR CREATING ALL TABLES](http://webprolearner.ueuo.com/class_des/query_create.php)

Comment: are you interested only in populating the records for each individual table?

Comment: @JohnWoo just one example of a query that will populate a record in the tables: `major_minor`, `class`, `section`, `faculty`,  `faculty_education`, `faculty_titles`, `office_hours`, `schedule` and `semester`

Comment: you need to have individual `INSERT` statement for every table. But make sure you `INSERT` record first on main tables so the referencing table will not throw an exception.

Comment: @JohnWoo Ok, thank you. Can you show me an example(answer) that will `INSERT` record on main tables and then `INSERT` record on the referencing tables using my model?

Comment: @JohnWoo did you see my last comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your table from your previous question, you need to `INSERT` records first on the independent table (*or the base tables*). Some of these tables are `event`, `semester`, `Major_Minor`, etc. These are called independent tables because *no foreign key constraints* were defined.

Sample Query to Insert on independent tables,

```
-- INSERTING records on table event
INSERT INTO event (ID, event_description, event_datetime) VALUES
  (1, 'hello', NOW()),
  (2, 'world', NOW()),
  (3, 'stack', NOW()),
  (4, 'overflow', NOW());

-- INSERTING records on table semester
INSERT INTO semester (ID, SEMESTER_NAme) VALUES
  (1, 'First Semester'), 
  (2, 'Second Semester'), 
  (3, 'Summer'); 

-- INSERTING records on table Major_Minor
INSERT INTO Major_Minor (ID, Major_Minor_Name) VALUES
  (1, 'Math'),
  (2, 'Science'),
  (3, 'English');

-- INSERTING records on table class
INSERT INTO class (ID, class_name) VALUES
  (1, 'Alpha'),
  (2, 'Beta'),
  (3, 'Gamma'),
  (4, 'Omega');
```

After records has been inserted, you can now `INSERT` on dependent tables. These are called *dependent* tables because foreign key constraints were defined on them. You can't add a value on certain fields it does not exist on the other table. Example of dependent table is `Major_Class_br` table,

```
-- INSERTING records on table Major_Class_br
INSERT INTO Major_Class_br (ID, Class_ID, Major_Minor_ID) VALUES
    (1,1,1),
    (2,1,2),
    (3,1,3),
    (4,2,1),
    (5,2,1),
    (6,4,2);
```

As you can see, the values for `Class_ID`, and `Major_Minor_ID` already existed on tables: `class` and `Major_Minor` because table `Major_Class_br` is dependent on them. To illustrate more on that, try executing the query below wherein the value for `Class_ID` doesn't exist yet on the `Class` table,

```
INSERT INTO Major_Class_br (ID, Class_ID, Major_Minor_ID) VALUES (7,5,2);
```

and you will see this error

> Schema Creation Failed: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign
>   key constraint fails (`databaseName`.`major_class_br`, CONSTRAINT
>   `cc_fk1` FOREIGN KEY (`Class_ID`) REFERENCES `class` (`ID`)):

- [**See SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/89fac/1)